# I want to add custom model pop up for buy a subscription

Tags: magento2, php, custom

I want to add custom model pop up with some message. I am creating three category A, B and C when I click on C category a model pop up will show with message please buy a subscription to product under C category.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the below code, you can create a **modal popup**.

```
<div id="modal-content">
    Content
</div>
<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Example Modal’,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__(‘OK’),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };
 
            var popup = modal(options, $('#modal-content’));
            $('#modal-content’).modal('openModal');
        }  
    );
</script>
```

To know more about modal popup events, you can check this Adobe official modal popup link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html